# How do I extract followers count from LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

**Use case:**

I'd like to extract the number of my followers, which is not the same as the number of connections (see [followers vs connections](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/follow-vs-connecthow-you-linkedin-michael-sherman)).

[image: Followers Count]

**What has been tried so far**

I've been browsing the API guide and googling around for some time, but only found the connection's API. Which is able to return the [total number of connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/full-profile?context=linkedin/consumer/context).

**Question**

- How to extract follower count from LinkedIn?
- Can it be done with the API?
- If not how can it be done with scraping it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a method in API but it requires correct CSRF cookies and username slug

You can open chrome console and filter requests with `networkinfo` to find more about which cookies to use

```js
const response = await fetch("https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/api/identity/profiles/{userSlug}/networkinfo", {
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/vnd.linkedin.normalized+json+2.1",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Csrf-Token": "ajax:xxxxx",
    Pragma: "no-cache",
    "X-Li-Lang": "en_US",
    "X-Li-Page-Instance": "urn:li:page:d_flagship3_profile_view_base;xxxxxxx==",
    "X-Li-Track": "{\"clientVersion\":\"1.2.2696\",\"osName\":\"web\",\"timezoneOffset\":3,\"deviceFormFactor\":\"DESKTOP\",\"mpName\":\"voyager-web\"}",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "X-Restli-Protocol-Version": "2.0.0"
  }
})
const json = await response.json();
console.log(json.data.followersCount);
```